# How can make a div vertically center to parent div

Tags: html, css

This is MY demo Work in JSFIDDLE

**NB without using table property**

http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/12/

I want to make the class `.box` should be vertically centered

CSS

```
.main{ height:300px; border:1px red solid;position:relative}
.box{width:40px; height:40px; background:red; }

/* for centering */
.box{ display: inline-block;position:relative; top:50% }
.main{ text-align: center; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="main">

 <div class="box"></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Use [calc](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/), `top: calc(50% - 20px);`  http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/SxxWV/18/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/20/

Comment: @tewathia Calc is not supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will Prefer to use CSS `after`

This line of CSS will work fine

```
.main:after{ content: ""; display: inline-block; 
height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Here id the **[Demo Work](http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/16/)**

Answer (score 5):

You need to subtract half of the height of the element you want to center, so in this case add the following to .box:

```
margin-top: -20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the box to `position: absolute` and then set the top and bottom to 0, and then set the margin to auto:

```
.box {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/23/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/29/)

```
.main{ height:300px; border:1px red solid;position:relative}
.box{width:40px; height:40px; background:red; }

/* for centering */
.box{ display: inline-block;position:relative; top:50%; margin-top:-20px; }
.main{ text-align: center; }
```

Good Luck